# Is it possible to put the server-side SignalR functionality in a different assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have two projects in my solution, an MVC 3 (UI) project and a class library (Domain).

I want to use SignalR from within the domain project because that is where the meat of the application logic is happening. I want to notify certain clients of some changes when they occur but the only place my application is aware of these states is inside the domain project (class library). It is inside there that I would like to inject SignalR's IConnection and grab the clients and execute a function on the clients.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Where the code lives doesn't matter.